# Eclipse + Apatna plug-in: unable to debug

Tags: ruby, eclipse, rubygems, aptana

Could you help me cope with the problem of organizing any IDE for Ruby so that I could debug my scripts.

I chose Eclipse + Aptana plug-in. But this is not a dogma. If there is an easier way, I would definitely change IDE and plugin or anything.

Well, let's return to what I have now. 
I seem to be unable to install ruby-debug-ide under my ordinary user.
Under root user I can execute gem install ruby-debug-ide. And I can see ruby-debug-ide in gem list --local. **But only when I login as a root user.**
Any messages beneath refer to ordinary user.

**What I have now:**

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Eclipse 3.8.1
- ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision  51636) [x86_64-linux]
- Aptana Studio 3.6.1 plug-in

**When in Eclipse I try to debug my app as ruby application, I get this:**

> /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in
>   `to_specs': Could not find 'ruby-debug-ide' (>= 0) among 23 total
>   gem(s) (Gem::LoadError) Checked in
>   'GEM_PATH=/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3:/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global',
>   execute`gem env`for more information    from
>   /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in`
>   to_spec'     from
>   /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in
>   `gem'     from /usr/local/bin/rdebug-ide:22:in`'

**When I run gem env:**

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.3 (2015-08-18 patchlevel 173) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/michael/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3
     - /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin
     - /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/bin
     - /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin
     - /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin
     - /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/bin
     - /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /usr/share/rvm/bin
     - /home/michael/.rvm/bin
     - /home/michael/.rvm/bin
     - /home/michael/.rvm/bin
```

**Then I try gem list --local:**

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activesupport (4.2.4)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
bigdecimal (1.2.6)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
columnize (0.9.0)
debase-ruby_core_source (0.8.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.1)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.8.2)
psych (2.0.8)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
sudo (0.1.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
```

**I try gem install ruby-debug-ide and get this:**

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby mkrf_conf.rb
Installing base gem
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151104-6046-7cu247.rb extconf.rb
checking for vm_core.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ruby-dir
    --without-ruby-dir
    --with-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
    --with-ruby-lib
    --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
/home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1060:in `block in have_header'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:911:in `block in checking_for'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:910:in `checking_for'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1059:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:31:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/debase-ruby_core_source-0.8.0/lib/debase/ruby_core_source.rb:18:in `call'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/debase-ruby_core_source-0.8.0/lib/debase/ruby_core_source.rb:18:in `create_makefile_with_core'
    from extconf.rb:47:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/debase-0.2.2.beta6 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/debase-0.2.2.beta6/gem_make.out
/home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:89:in `run'
  /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:36:in `block in build'
  /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tempfile.rb:319:in `open'
  /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:19:in `build'
  /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `block (2 levels) in build_extension'
  /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `chdir'
  /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `block in build_extension'
  /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `synchronize'
  /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_extension'
  /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
  /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
  /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
  /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/installer.rb:702:in `build_extensions'
  /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/installer.rb:250:in `install'
  /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:166:in `block in install'
  /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:150:in `each'
  /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:150:in `install'
  /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:404:in `install'
  mkrf_conf.rb:35:in `rescue in <main>'
  mkrf_conf.rb:28:in `<main>'

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem myself with the following code :

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
```